# Tampermonkey add iframe problem - Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension

Tags: iframe, tampermonkey

I would like to add iframe on specific URL and everything kind of works but iframe content is not loaded. In iframe I see message "Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension".

[image]

I disabled all other extensions (except Tampermonkey). Apparently Tampemonkey is blocking this behaviour for some reason. Any idea how to do this?

In JS console I see:

```
chrome-extension://dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/:1 Refused to frame 
'https://xyz123.com/' because it violates the following Content Security 
Policy directive: "child-src 'self' docs.google.com fast.wistia.net 
js.stripe.com platform.twitter.com player.vimeo.com staticxx.facebook.com 
www.facebook.com web.facebook.com www.youtube.com". Note that 'frame-src' was 
not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Looks like the site's CSP forbids iframing. I think you'll have to either 1) write an [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and spoof the CSP header via webRequest API or 2) install a separate extension that allows spoofing/modifying HTTP headers, including CSP.

Comment: @wOxxOm I would love to mark this as an accepted answer! Thanks a ton!